# TypeError: authContext is undefined reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

**When trying to use auth context in the App.js file it shows undefined. Please help me out in finding the mistake i am doing. Thank you for the help.**

App.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";
import Home from "./components/pages/Home";
import About from "./components/pages/About";
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
import Alerts from "./components/layout/Alerts";

import setAuthToken from "../src/utils/setAuthToken";

//PRIVATE ROUTE
import PrivateRoute from "./components/routing/PrivateRoute";

//CONTEXT IMPORTS
import ContactState from "./context/contact/ContactState";
import AuthState from "./context/auth/AuthState";
import AuthContext from "./context/auth/authContext";
import AlertState from "./context/alerts/AlertState";

import "./App.css";

if (localStorage.token) {
    setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
}

const App = () => {
    const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
    useEffect(() => {
        authContext.loadUser();

        //eslint-disable-next-line
    });

    return (
        <AuthState>
            <ContactState>
                <AlertState>
                    <Router>
                        <Fragment>
                            <Navbar />
                            <div className='container'>
                                <Alerts />
                                <Switch>
                                    <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Home} />
                                    <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
                                    <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
                                    <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
                                </Switch>
                            </div>
                        </Fragment>
                    </Router>
                </AlertState>
            </ContactState>
        </AuthState>
    );
};

export default App;
```

**Also, in Home.js i am using context the same way but there shows no error in this file and the app runs perfectly.**
Home.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";

import Contacts from "../contact/Contacts";
import ContactForm from "../contact/ContactForm";
import ContactFilter from "../contact/ContactFilter";

import AuthContext from "../../context/auth/authContext";

const Home = () => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    authContext.loadUser();

    //eslint-disable-next-line
  });

  return (
    <div className="grid-2">
      <div>
        <ContactForm />
      </div>
      <div>
        <ContactFilter />
        <Contacts />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

authContext.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const authContext = createContext();

export default authContext;
```

authReducer.js

```
import {
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_FAIL,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  USER_LOADED,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGOUT,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
} from "../types";

const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOADED:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loading: false,
        user: action.payload,
      };
    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: null,
      };
    case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      localStorage.setItem("token", action.payload.token);
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loading: false,
      };
    case REGISTER_FAIL:
    case AUTH_ERROR:
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
    case LOGOUT:
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        isAuthenticated: null,
        loading: false,
        user: null,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

authState.js

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import setAuthToken from "../../utils/setAuthToken";
import AuthContext from "./authContext";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";
import {
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_FAIL,
  USER_LOADED,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGOUT,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
} from "../types";

//CREATE INITIAL STATE
const AuthState = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    user: null,
    loading: true,
    error: null,
  };

  //STATE ALLOWS US TO USE ANYTHING WE PUT IN THE STATE
  //DISPATCH ALLOWS US TO DISPATCH OBJECTS,ACTIONS,METHODS OR ANYTHING TO REDUCER
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialState);

  //ACTIONS

  //LOAD USER - WHICH IS GOING TO TAKE CARE OF WHICH USER IS LOGGED AND ITS GOING TO HIT THAT AUTH ENDPOINT AND GET THE USER DATA
  const loadUser = async () => {
    // LOAD TOKEN INTO GLOBAL HEADERS

    setAuthToken(localStorage.token);

    try {
      const res = await axios.get("/api/auth");

      dispatch({
        type: USER_LOADED,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: AUTH_ERROR,
      });
    }
  };

  //REGISTER USER - WHICH SIGNS THE USER UP AND GETS A TOKEN BACK
  const register = async (formData) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    try {
      const res = await axios.post("api/user", formData, config);

      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
      loadUser();
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_FAIL,
        payload: err.response.data.msg,
      });
    }
  };

  //LOGIN USER - WHICH WILL LOG THE USER IN AND GET THE TOKEN
  const login = async (formData) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Types": "application/json",
      },
    };

    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/api/auth", formData, config);

      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
      loadUser();
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL,
        payload: err.response.data.msg,
      });
    }
  };

  //LOGOUT - WHICH WILL DESTROY THE TOKEN AND JUST CLEAR EVERYTHIN UP
  const logout = () => dispatch({ type: LOGOUT });

  //CLEAR_ERRORS - TO CLEAR OUT ANY ERRORS IN THE STATE
  const clearErrors = () =>
    dispatch({
      type: CLEAR_ERRORS,
    });

  //BY SURROUNDING THE COMPONENT IN THE SPECIFIC PROVIDER TAGS WE GET ACCESS TO THE STATE AND FUCNTIONS OF THE PROVIDER
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        token: state.token,
        isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
        loading: state.loading,
        user: state.user,
        error: state.error,
        register,
        loadUser,
        login,
        logout,
        clearErrors,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthState;
```

[image: The error statement]

[image: The folder structure]

**The above image shows the folder structure**

Answer (score 1):

You might need to wrap your App.js file in an AuthContext provider, probably in your index.js file.

```html
ReactDOM.render(
    <AuthContextProvider>
        <App />
    </AuthContextProvider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```